# Format code block quickly?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

What is a quick way to format many lines of code for Stack Overflow?

I insert all 4xNLines spaces each time one by one, and wondering that there should be quicker way to do this, but can't find it in FAQ as well as on meta.

P.S Found one question about shift+enter, but it doesn't work for me. I'm using MacOS10.7, and Opera 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the two `{}` in the editor toolbar, right above the big textarea where you type your question/answer?  Highlight the code, and click that `{}` in the toolbar. This will format your code very quickly:

```
function test() {
    alert("hello world");
}
```

Pressing `{}` on the above code automatically put it inside a code block.

Comment: Or alternatively, select all and hit ctrl+k

Comment: jmort253, Thanks! (I will accept your answer in 10 minutes:) ) Bart, thanks too.

Comment: that alternative comment have more votes than your answer o_o

Comment: @ajax I simply leave brilliant comments.... :)

Comment: @Bart oh, I thought it was from jmort, my "your answer" is incorrect