# A badge for comments whose score exceeds the answer score

Tags: feature-request, comments, badge-request, score

I've seen a few situations where a comment's score exceeds the answer score, and the comment is always exceptional (be it [hilarious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/tags-foobar-versus-foo-bar#comment4787_2835) or [constructive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144125/format-code-block-quickly#comment410407_144126)). Shouldn't these comments deserve a badge? I think it should only be a bronze, as it's really not that hard. It would also be a multi-award badge. I think this promotes good commenting behavior, at least as much as the <kbd>Reversal</kbd> badge does.

NAMES:
<kbd>Nice Assist</kbd>
<kbd>Spotlight Thief</kbd>
<kbd>Sidekick</kbd>

DESCRIPTION:
Posted a comment which outscored the post

Something I'm still not sure about is if this badge should be for comments on answers only or questions too.

Comment: Call it "Son of Summer Love" maybe

Comment: maybe also require that the answer has a score of at least 2-3?

Comment: @Brad There should definitely be a minimum score for both. Otherwise, the badge would be dished out to a +1 comment on a 0 score answer, and that happens often enough. 2 sounds good to me.

Answer (score 12):

The main problem I see with this is most users throw comment votes around like they're nothing. They don't give or take away reputation, so users are much more lenient on what kinds of comments they upvote than on actual posts they upvote, which makes it much easier for a comment to achieve a higher score than the actual post it's on, especially here on Meta where users throw comment votes at anything that mentions unicorns or Jon Skeet.

More importantly, what good behavior is this promoting? We already have a badge for leaving 10 comments that have a score of at least 5 to encourage good commenting. Why would this one be necessary at all? This badge sounds like a multiple-award badge. If that's the true intention, the criteria would need to be extremely strict or there would just be a flood of useless badges being awarded non-stop.

Comment: Also: if it's really a good comment (i.e. not just a popular joke), then chances are it would make an even better answer (or should be edited into the appropriate answer) for best effect.