# What are the chances of getting auto-prettier code formatting on code blocks on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144126/341564) taught me that highlighting a code block and clicking the curly brackets icons auto-formats the code block.

Many developers, me included, are used to the comfort of `format-on-save` available on all the popular IDEs. I would love to be able to toggle a checkbox of "auto-format code blocks on post" and have [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) run its magic. I understand that this would mean one needs to specify the programming language of each of the code block with (```js or so). However this seems like a reasonable ask for allowing such a great, time-saving functionality (IMHO).

Partial code-blocks or pseudo-code could be ignored as those would be challenging for Prettier. The code would have to be a valid, syntax-perfect code.

Comment: See our FAQ [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work): you can use the language identifier `default` to have the highlighter automatically infer the language. It's also done automatically if two tags have conflicting syntax hints. Are you suggesting that `default` be made the current default if none of the tags have highlighting hints specified, instead of the current behavior of applying no highlighting?

Comment: *"prettier"* = *"[Prettier](https://prettier.io/)"*?

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog I think the OP is asking not about code highlighting, but primarily about using Prettier (or similar) to automatically format the code, which, admittedly, is a huge problem over on SO. That said, finding reasonable defaults will be a tough task.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine yes, defaults will have to be decided upon for each programming language. As the checkbox could be optional I can't see any complains for this.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yes, updated the question

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog IMO both highlighting and standardized code formatting can help the reader of a question. Offering auto-formatting with prettier can achieve auto-formatting for the poster with low friction.

Comment: Personally, I'd support this, @Guy. Atrocious code formatting (when it is even formatted as code in the first place) is a huge problem over on SO (and our sister sites too). I think it's been proposed before, but I am not sure what the reception was. Anyways, the unfortunate part is that this proposal will require SE's dev time, so it takes it straight to "a man can dream" territory :) However, SE plans to roll out the new editor soon, and it is opensource, so there is a chance that we can strap on such a feature ourselves, but it needs somebody to champion it over on GitHub.

Comment: Off-site duplicates: "[Can we add a button "Format with Prettier" to the toolbar when editing posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390208/3648282)" and even easier: "[Let's have a "Tidy Up" button!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261249/3648282)" - Our closest dupe (not very close): "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/282094)" (some of the answers touch on "format" and not "highlighting"). --- So, there's no really great duplicate (on MSE); this is an unduplicated Feature Request.

Comment: I'd be all for this if it were an optional trigger of some sort; I'd rather not have all code blocks forcefully formatted to Prettier's notoriously opinionated style in cases where it was unwanted.